# VBA - how to specify valid users to perform certain action

Tags: vba, excel

I had created some mandatory cells beforeclose, and would like to have some user to escae the mandatory cells. Found these code from [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_winother/excel-vba-only-run-macro-if-your-windows-user-name/d8f29b1f-82de-4f7f-8730-c8cca66e1206?auth=1), trying to edit the codes but it does not work.

Hope someone could explain it to me.
The u, sers1, u, sers2 are the users that no need to fill up the mandatory cells, they can close the workbook while leaving the cells blank. The username format in the excel is `u, ser1`.

Appreciate any suggestions and help.

```
Function IsInvalidUser() As Boolean
Dim asUsers() As String
asUsers = Split("u, ser1.u, ser2", ".")
IsInvalidUser = IsError(Application.Match(Environ("UserName"), asUsers, 0))
End Function

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
If Not (IsInvalidUser) And Cells(2, 8).Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Cell H2 requires user input", vbInformation, "Please filled up the mandatory cells"
    Cancel = True
ElseIf Not (IsInvalidUser) And Cells(4, 4).Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Cell D4 requires user input", vbInformation, "Please filled up the mandatory cells"
    Cancel = True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: (a) Where/when did you check `asUsers` and decide that it was empty? Were you stepping through the `IsInvalidUser` function at the time?  (That would be the only time it would/should have a value.)  (b) Are your usernames (i.e. the name you login to the computer with) in the format `u, ser1` or is that just the username within Excel?  (`Environ("UserName")` is picking up an environment string, e.g. mine is `X312651` even though my user name shown in Excel would be something more meaningful.)

Comment: (c) You are testing for `Not IsInvalidUser` but I think you want `If IsInvalidUser And Cells(2, 8).Value = "" Then` - i.e. if the user **isn't** in your list and the cell is blank then display the message.

Comment: (a)Hi, I checking beforeSave. using the example i found online `Dim x As Integer
x = 5.5
MsgBox "value is " & x`. I just modify my x to my variable name.(b) The `u, ser1` is the username within excel and computer. I found it using "File" => "Options" => "Username" under General

Comment: (c) YES!!! That's what I'm looking for and trying to accomplish.

Comment: (b) The user name shown under File/Options/Username is not necessarily the value returned by `Environ("UserName")`.  Go to the Immediate Window within the VBA environment and type in `?Environ("UserName")` to see what your own username is on the computer and just make sure it is in the same format.  (c) If you change your `If` statement as per my previous comment and your code still isn't working, I would bet that the issue is with my point (b) and you just aren't looking for the right user names.

Comment: @YowE3K I had to read your comments twice before I noticed the method read `IsInvalidUser`  instead of `isValid`.  Thanks

Comment: @ThomasInzina I was about to comment on your answer that you needed to get rid of the `Not`, and then noticed that you had switched it to `IsValidUser` :D

Comment: FWIW - If you change `Environ("UserName")` to `Application.UserName` then you **will** be checking on the user name given at File / Options / Username.  (But, of course, that would then make it easy for anyone to change their username to bypass your tests. :D  Not that they can't change what is returned by `Environ("UserName")`, but it is a bit easier to change your name in Excel than at the system level.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the array would be difficult to maintain.  I would use a list on a hidden worksheet.  A Scripting.Dictionary would also work well and have the added advantage of being able to compare text.

```
Function IsValidUser() As Boolean
    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        .CompareMode = vbTextCompare
        .Add "u, ser1", vbNullString
        .Add "u, ser2", vbNullString
        IsValidUser = .Exists(Environ("UserName"))
    End With
End Function

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not IsValidUser Then
        If Cells(2, 8).Value = "" Then
            MsgBox "Cell H2 requires user input", vbInformation, "Please filled up the mandatory cells"
        ElseIf Cells(4, 4).Value = "" Then
            MsgBox "Cell D4 requires user input", vbInformation, "Please filled up the mandatory cells"
        End If
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

**Note:**  I changed the logic up to check for valid users.

Comment: I've just edited your answer to only set Cancel = True when a value is missing. It's pending peer review.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the answer. For those who tried to do the same as me, please read the comment written by @YowE3K.`The user name shown under File/Options/Username is not necessarily the value returned by Environ("UserName"). Go to the Immediate Window within the VBA environment and type in ?Environ("UserName") to see what your own username is on the computer and just make sure it is in the same format. ` 

The `u,ser1` needs to be correct.